# What happens when all productions in a grammar are useless?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have this grammar, and I've been asked to eliminate all useless productions.

```
S-> aS | AB
A-> bA
B-> AA
```

Now it's pretty easy to see that every production is useless because none of them produce terminal strings. So does this just result in an empty language?

Comment: Yes, the language of this grammar is $\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is saying that the language of this grammar is lambda the same thing?

Comment: No: $\{\lambda\}$ is the one-word language whose only word is the empty word, while $\varnothing$ is the language with no words at all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but wanted to be sure. Cheers! @BrianM.Scott